# How to split paragraphs into sentences?

Tags: java, regex, string, split, text-segmentation

Please have a look at the following.

```
String[]sentenceHolder = titleAndBodyContainer.split("\n|\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.");
```

This is how I tried to split a paragraph into sentences. But, there is a problem. My paragraph includes dates like `Jan. 13, 2014`, words like `U.S` and numbers like `2.2`. They all got splitted by the above code. So basically, this code splits lot of 'dots' whether it is a full stop or not.

I tried `String[]sentenceHolder = titleAndBodyContainer.split(".\n");` and `String[]sentenceHolder = titleAndBodyContainer.split("\\.");` as well. All failed.

How can I split a paragraph into sentences "properly"?

Comment: Look at using a sentence [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/about.html)

Comment: You can start by defining `properly` in terms that the computer can understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654738/regex-split-text-document-into-sentences

Comment: This is not a trivial task, phew... E.g. the sentence "In Sweden a common name is Jan. 31, at least, people have this name.", would be virtually impossible to parse, without some kind of context aware parser. (Edit: "Jan" **is** a common christian name in Sweden ;))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674850/converting-a-sentence-string-to-a-string-array-of-words-in-java

Answer (score 19):

You can try this

```
String str = "This is how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence. But, there is a problem. My paragraph includes dates like Jan.13, 2014 , words like U.S and numbers like 2.2. They all got split by the above code.";

Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher reMatcher = re.matcher(str);
while (reMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(reMatcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
This is how I tried to split a paragraph into a sentence.
But, there is a problem.
My paragraph includes dates like Jan.13, 2014 , words like U.S and numbers like 2.2.
They all got split by the above code.
```

Comment: Hmm... Where did the space after "Jan." go... What a mystery ;)

Comment: What does the regex mean? I'm newbie at java, I'm interested to learn about your regex :-(

Comment: @Wingzero Please refer theses.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html;
http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: What initiates the `\n`  in the regex to split sentences? Is using .MULTILINE and .COMMENTS really necessary?

Comment: @UtherPendragon, this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687929/462347 can deal with the «`U.S. `» case.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] sentenceHolder = titleAndBodyContainer.split("(?i)(?<=[.?!])\\S+(?=[a-z])");
```

Try this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will split the paragraph by `.` `?` `!`:

```
String a[]=str.split("\\.|\\?|\\!");
```

You can put any symbol after `\\` which you want to use and use `|` to separate each condition.

Comment: why not split("[.?!]") ?