# .NET Regex for full stop at the end of a sentence

Tags: .net, regex

I want to match a full stop at the end of each sentence in a paragraph of text.

**There must be atleast 3 words before the fullstop(.)**

This is to ensure only full stops at the end of sentences are counted. Periods in  `Microsoft v 3.2.1` are skipped! Please note that the words may not necessarily contain latin characters. I plan to use in other languages so we can't use [a-Z] here!

What i tried `\b.+\b\s+\b.+\b\s+\b.+\b[.]`
But this selects the whole sentence!

Probably one can use a if else construct? if `\b.+\b\s+\b.+\b\s+\b.+\b[.]` is found, select the dot or else don't. Is it possible?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Is there a class of students having the same idea? (Let the people att SO do the heavy lifting... ;)) This was asked half an hour ago... [How to...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430447/how-to-split-paragraphs-into-sentences)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here's a go at it:

```
(?:(?:\s|^|\.)[^\s\d.]+){3}(\.)
```

Expl.: (Non capturing) find a space, full stop or start of line followed by any number (at least one) of characters that isn't a space, digit or a full stop. Repeat this 3 times. Then capture a full stop :D Done!

Check it out [here](http://regex101.com/r/mA4lR8).

Regards

Comment: Amazing! You almost got it. One small problem though. Right now, this selects the three words along with the dot. I am using a search and replace algorithm, as a result of which the three words before the dot also get replaced. Is there a way to replace only the "dot"?

Comment: Got it! used `(?<name>(?:(?:\s|^|\.)[^\s\d.]+){3})(\.)` in the find box and `${name}` in the replace ;)